# Android Power Button Pressed

Tags: android

I am trying to create an application that could respond when the power button is pressed. To be more specific, which would respond to it when pressed 2 or 3 times.

For now, I tried the following:

```
public class SMSKey extends BroadcastReceiver{

    static int countPowerOff = 0;
    private Activity activity = null;
    public SMSKey(Activity activity){
        this.activity = activity;
    }

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        if(intent.getAction().equals(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_OFF)){
            countPowerOff++;
        }else if(intent.getAction().equals(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_ON)){
            if(countPowerOff == 2){
                Intent i = new Intent(activity, SMSOptions.class);
                activity.startActivity(i);
            }
        }
    }

}
```

and in my **manifest**:

```
<receiver android:name=".SMSKey">
        <intent-filter >
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.SCREEN_OFF"/>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.SCREEN_ON"/>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.ACTION_POWER_CONNECTED"/>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.ACTION_POWER_DISCONNECTED"/>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.ACTION_SHUTDOWN"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```

finally in my **MainActivty.java**:

```
IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_ON);
filter.addAction(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_OFF);
SMSKey mReceiver = new SMSKey(this);
registerReceiver(mReceiver, filter);
```

Even though this works, it only works for the 1st time, it won't work on the 2nd or 3rd attempt when the power button is pressed. Why is that so ??

And another question: as you can see, I am using this KeyPress event in my MainActivity, which means the application is to be open all the time. Is there any other way that I can implement this without getting into the MainActivity.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not even an Android problem. You never reset your `countPowerOff` variable after you have received the 3 key presses. Even after having done that you must consider adding an alarm that will reset your `countPowerOff` variable to zero after some small timeout. It will allow you to avoid situations where the user does not intend to interact with your application and just presses the button, but it still gets counted.

As to your second question, try implementing an [IntentService](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html#ExtendingIntentService).

Comment: how do i reset this ? Do i declare the countPowerOff to zero when its equal to 3 ? And about this timeout. How is that done ? I am a little new so please don't mind the question.

Comment: Yes, you set your variable to zero in the `if(countPowerOff == 2) { /*...*/ }` statement. For the timeout i guess you can use a [Handler](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html).

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution

```
public class MyReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
private static int countPowerOff = 0;

public MyReceiver (){

}

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent){
if (intent.getAction().equals(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_OFF)){    
    Log.e("In on receive", "In Method:  ACTION_SCREEN_OFF");
    countPowerOff++;
}
else if (intent.getAction().equals(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_ON)){
    Log.e("In on receive", "In Method:  ACTION_SCREEN_ON");
}
else if(intent.getAction().equals(Intent.ACTION_USER_PRESENT)){
    Log.e("In on receive", "In Method:  ACTION_USER_PRESENT");
    if (countPowerOff >= 2)
    {
        countPowerOff=0;
        Toast.makeText(context, "MAIN ACTIVITY IS BEING CALLED ", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        Intent i = new Intent(context, About.class);
        i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK|Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
        context.startActivity(i);
    }
}
  }
 }
```