# How to perform some function of my app when power button is pressed?

Tags: android, launch, eventtrigger

I want to send an email when the power button is pressed twice ? I have tried so many codes already but none is working so far. Can anybody help ?

This is my **service class**

```html
public class UpdateService extends Service {

    BroadcastReceiver mReceiver;
int counter=0;

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        // register receiver that handles screen on and screen off logic
        IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_ON);
        filter.addAction(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_OFF);
        mReceiver = new Receiver();
        registerReceiver(mReceiver, filter);
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {

        unregisterReceiver(mReceiver);
        Log.i("onDestroy Reciever", "Called");

        super.onDestroy();
    }

    @Override
    public void onStart(Intent intent, int startId) {
        boolean screenOn = intent.getBooleanExtra("screen_state", false);
        if (!screenOn) {
            counter += 1;
            Log.i("screenON *****************", "Called");
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Awake" + counter, Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                    .show();
        } else {
            counter += 1;
            Log.i("screenOFF ******************", "Called");
            Toast.makeText(this, "slept" + counter, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        if (counter >= 4) {
            Log.e("counter is -->", "" + counter);
            counter = 0;
            Log.e("counter is after clearance -->", "" + counter);
            Log.e("************-***********", "Boooyah");
            Toast.makeText(this, "Booyaaaha !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


            Intent email = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
            email.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, new String[]{"dracmore@outlook.com"});
            email.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "TFS");
            email.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "This is the sample Message of my email");
            email.setType("email/rfc822");
            startActivity(Intent.createChooser(email, "Send Mail Via"));
            email.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
            email.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_FROM_BACKGROUND);
            startActivity(email);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }
}
```

And this little one is **the receiver**

```html
public class Receiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    private boolean screenOff;

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        if (intent.getAction().equals(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_OFF)) {
            screenOff = true;
        } else if (intent.getAction().equals(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_ON)) {
            screenOff = false;
        }
        Intent i = new Intent(context, UpdateService.class);
        i.putExtra("screen_state", screenOff);
        context.startService(i);
    }

}
```

**Manifest**

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.apkglobal.transarent">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE"></uses-permission>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MANAGE_OWN_CALLS"></uses-permission>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.DISABLE_KEYGUARD"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"></uses-permission>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SEND_SMS"></uses-permission>
    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <receiver android:name=".Receiver"/>
        <service android:name=".UpdateService"/>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

The problem is the  **Code works fine when the screen turns off and on But i want this code to *work when the power button is pressed 2 times or 3 times in succession***

Comment: post your current code and we'll try to help

Comment: This is a nice idea, I would be interested in what you tried already too

Comment: Please help me what can I do for recognizing successive power button Clicks.

Answer (score 1):

[Kindly check the link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18815087/android-power-button-pressed)

By using broadcast receiver you can get the action of screen off, with help of that you can able to track the action.